# C# console app to process FFMPEG jpg stream output

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am looking some tip or idea in order to process an stream of jpg files created by a fFMPEG command.

There is a way to split the outpuStream to capture each jpg file?

Here is the command
ffmpeg -i rtsp://somertsp:554 -an -f image2pipe -vf fps=fps=5 -

I execute that command using a C# application.

Here is a example code

```
class Program
{
    private static BackgroundWorker worker;
    private static MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
    private static BinaryWriter bufferWriter = new BinaryWriter(buffer);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
        string arguments = @"-i rtsp://xxx:yyy@v5demo.wavestore.com:554/rtsp/00004 -an -f image2pipe -vf fps=fps=5 -qscale 0 -";

        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(file, arguments);
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.Start();

        worker.RunWorkerAsync(process);
        process.WaitForExit();

    }

    static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // save the image
    }

    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            var internalWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            Process p = e.Argument as Process;
            buffer = new MemoryStream();
            bufferWriter = new BinaryWriter(buffer);
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                   //get the jpg image
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // Log the error, continue processing the live stream
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) {}` - best code ever!

Comment: heheh yes, sorry I tried to omit code that don't match to this example. just to focus on the good parts.

Comment: Actually the good part would be to _never ever_ catch any exceptions at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257939/faster-way-to-write-image-to-process-standardinput-basestream helps?

Comment: @cDima its a different scenario, in that example C# app is a image provider and ffmpeg will process from the input stream. In my case I am the consumer of the FFMPEG stream.

Comment: @UweKeim mmm maybe yes, but in this case ReadUint16 could throw 3 different exceptions. Can you let me know other wasy to manage it?

Comment: How about only reading an UINT16 when there is a UINT16 to expect (i.e. follow the spec)?